# How can Murph look so young after all this time?

Tags: plot-explanation, interstellar

By the end of *Interstellar* a little maneuvering around the blackhole took Cooper 51 earth years and the time on water the planet took 23 earth years.

So, after almost 90 years Cooper reached the inside of the black hole. But when he was transmitting the Morse code to Murph she was looking pretty young. How is this possible?

Answer (score 8):

The idea is not just that he is just transmitting the code across space when he is in the Tesseract within the black-hole.

The idea is that he is transmitting across both space **and time**.

The Tesseract he floats around within the black hole is an artificial construct to allow Cooper to find the right moment in space and time to communicate with Murph the information she needs to save humanity.

He sees her at various stages in her life in that bedroom, as a child, and even himself before he leaves the planet.  He is able to weakly interact with the past by manipulating the dust, the watch-hand and even pushing the books off the shelves in frustration.  He is the ghost behind her shelves at the start of the movie.

Cooper finds the right time when she is present in the room and old enough to understand the meaning of what he is transmitting.

Comment: Ehhhhh he did find the right time where she was present in the room but it wasn't because she was old enough to understand what he was transmitting. I would argue that, and he even kind of explains it to TARS, that he found the right WAY to transmit the information to her. That's why he encoded the information into the watch, he knew that she would keep the watch long enough until she was ready to understand its meaning. And that's exactly what we see happen.

Comment: @ArinZandbergen ... yeah, I could live with that explanation too.  But the answer to the original question is still the same, she's young because he's communicating across time.

Comment: Slightly more specifically, there are no further time shenanigans after Coop entering the event horizon, so the reasonable inference is that Murph at this time is as old as she is when Coop sees her again (i.e. well into her senior years).